# D3 Force Layout with text Label And Icon

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Can somebody familiar with d3js.org. I am having problem showing a text label on the circles. If anyone has the experience of successfully implementing them I am willing to take a look at the solution.

Here's my code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8"><style>
@import url(../style.css);


.link {
stroke: #000;
stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.node {
fill: #000;
stroke: #fff;
stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.node.a { fill: #1f77b4; }
.node.b { fill: #ff7f0e; }
.node.c { fill: #2ca02c; }
</style>
<body>
<a href="../index.html">cola.js home</a>
<h1>Continuous layout while graph is changing</h1>
<script src="../extern/d3.v3.js"></script>
<script src="../cola.min.js"></script>
<script>

var width = 960,
    height = 500;

var color = d3.scale.category10();

var nodes = [],
    links = [];

var force = cola.d3adaptor()
    .nodes(nodes)
    .links(links)
    .linkDistance(140)
    .size([width, height])
    .on("tick", tick);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var node = svg.selectAll(".node"),
    link = svg.selectAll(".link");

// 1. Add three nodes and three links.
setTimeout(function () {
    var a = { id: "a", name: "A"  }, b = { id: "b", name: "B" }; //, c = { id: "c" }
    nodes.push(a, b);
    links.push({ source: a, target: b }, { source: a, target: b }); //, { source: b, target: c }
    start();
}, 0);

// 2. Remove node B and associated links.
setTimeout(function () {
    nodes.splice(1, 1); // remove b
    links.shift(); // remove a-b
    links.pop(); // remove b-c
    start();
}, 3000);

// Add node B back.
setTimeout(function () {
    var a = nodes[0], b = { id: "b", x: 0, y: 0 }, c = nodes[1];
    nodes.push(b);
    links.push({ source: a, target: b }, { source: c, target: b });
    start();
}, 6000);

function start() {
    link = link.data(force.links(), function (d) { return d.source.id + "-" + d.target.id; });
    // Initial end positions are at the source... that way when we add a new target node with transitions,
    // the edges appear to grow out of the source
    link.enter().insert("line", ".node").attr("class", "link")
        .attr("x1", function (d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function (d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function (d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y2", function (d) { return d.source.y; });
    link.exit().remove();

    node = node.data(force.nodes(), function (d) { return d.id; });
    node.enter().append("circle").attr("class", function (d) { return "node " + d.id; }).attr("r", 8);
    node.append("svg:text").attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    node.exit().remove();

    force.start();
}

function tick() {
    node.transition().attr("cx", function (d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function (d) { return d.y; })

    link.transition().attr("x1", function (d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function (d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function (d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function (d) { return d.target.y; });
}



</script>
</body>
```

Comment: You weren't seeing anything because you appended the text node, but didn't actually set the text to anything. Try something like this instead: `node.append("svg:text").attr("text-anchor", "middle").text(function(d){ return d.id; /* or whatever you want */; })`.

Comment: That didnt work for me. By the way here is the link where I got the code . http://marvl.infotech.monash.edu/webcola/examples/modifyinggraph.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a group element for each node which groups the circle and text.

```
  var nodeData = node.data(force.nodes(), function(d) {
    return d.id;
  });

  node = nodeData.enter().append("g");

  node.append("circle").attr("class", function(d) {
    return "node " + d.id;
  }).attr("r", 8);

  node.append("svg:text")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("dy", ".30em")
    .text(function(d) { 
      return d.name //The text content to be shown as label
    })

  nodeData.exit().remove();
```

Then update the group position in tick function.

```
function tick() {

  node.transition().attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
  })

  link.transition().attr("x1", function(d) {
      return d.source.x;
    })
    .attr("y1", function(d) {
      return d.source.y;
    })
    .attr("x2", function(d) {
      return d.target.x;
    })
    .attr("y2", function(d) {
      return d.target.y;
    });
}
```

Working Code Snippet:

```js
var width = 960,
  height = 500;

var color = d3.scale.category10();

var nodes = [],
  links = [];

var force = cola.d3adaptor()
  .nodes(nodes)
  .links(links)
  .linkDistance(140)
  .size([width, height])
  .on("tick", tick);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);

var node = svg.selectAll(".node"),
  link = svg.selectAll(".link");

// 1. Add three nodes and three links.
setTimeout(function() {
  var a = {
      id: "a",
      name: "A"
    },
    b = {
      id: "b",
      name: "B"
    }; //, c = { id: "c" }
  nodes.push(a, b);
  links.push({
    source: a,
    target: b
  }, {
    source: a,
    target: b
  }); //, { source: b, target: c }
  start();
}, 0);

// 2. Remove node B and associated links.
setTimeout(function() {
  nodes.splice(1, 1); // remove b
  links.shift(); // remove a-b
  links.pop(); // remove b-c
  start();
}, 3000);

// Add node B back.
setTimeout(function() {
  var a = nodes[0],
    b = {
      id: "b",
      x: 0,
      y: 0
    },
    c = nodes[1];
  nodes.push(b);
  links.push({
    source: a,
    target: b
  }, {
    source: c,
    target: b
  });
  start();
}, 6000);

function start() {
  link = link.data(force.links(), function(d) {
    return d.source.id + "-" + d.target.id;
  });
  // Initial end positions are at the source... that way when we add a new target node with transitions,
  // the edges appear to grow out of the source
  link.enter().insert("line", ".node").attr("class", "link")
    .attr("x1", function(d) {
      return d.source.x;
    })
    .attr("y1", function(d) {
      return d.source.y;
    })
    .attr("x2", function(d) {
      return d.source.x;
    })
    .attr("y2", function(d) {
      return d.source.y;
    });
  link.exit().remove();

  var nodeData = node.data(force.nodes(), function(d) {
    return d.id;
  });
  
  node = nodeData.enter().append("g");
  
  node.append("circle").attr("class", function(d) {
    return "node " + d.id;
  }).attr("r", 8);
  
  node.append("svg:text")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("dy", ".30em")
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.name
    })

  nodeData.exit().remove();


  force.start();
}

function tick() {
  
  node.transition().attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
  })

  link.transition().attr("x1", function(d) {
      return d.source.x;
    })
    .attr("y1", function(d) {
      return d.source.y;
    })
    .attr("x2", function(d) {
      return d.target.x;
    })
    .attr("y2", function(d) {
      return d.target.y;
    });
}
```

```css
.link {
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
.node {
  fill: #000;
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
.node.a {
  fill: #1f77b4;
}
.node.b {
  fill: #ff7f0e;
}
.node.c {
  fill: #2ca02c;
}
text {
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://marvl.infotech.monash.edu/webcola/cola.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks. Works for me :)